# How is the word "Eboracum" stressed in Latin?

Tags: pronunciation, stress

John Walker in his work [A Key to the Classical Pronunciation of Greek, Latin, and Scripture Proper Names](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=91Zve0-8wBwC&printsec=frontcover&hl=uk#v=onepage&q=Eboracum&f=false) suggests pronouncing it as "Ebóracum":

[image: John Walker. A Key to the Classical Pronunciation of Greek, Latin, and Scripture Proper Names.]

Are there any other sources of this word's pronunciation?

Comment: I'm guessing Walker puts a short *ă* because it got syncopated later ("York"). But that syncope happened after the word had gotten totally reanalyzed in English, so I wouldn't put much weight on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the underlying Celtic form was in fact Eburākon, then one would expect it to have been borrowed into Latin with a long ā and hence pronounced with the accent on the paenultima.